# HTML5 Javascript . how to Save Textarea input then loading it via buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I have a project I'm working on where there's a "Save" button that saves the user's data to `localStorage` and there's a "Load" button that loads a user's saved data from `localStorage`. However, it's not working. Can someone please help me fix this problem?

HTML:

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="text"></textarea>
<br/><button id="save">Save</button>

<button id="load">Load</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function doSave(){
    var txt = text.value;
    localStorage.storedText= txt;
}

function doLoad(){
    text.value = localStorage.storedText;
}

window.onload = function(){
    saveButton = document.getElementById("save");
    saveButton.onclick = doSave();
    loadButton = document.getElementById("load");
    loadButton.onclick = doLoad();
    textarea = document.getElementById("text");
};
```

Comment: But it doesn't? What is your question?

Comment: @putvande Use context clues. It's to save what input he writes into the `<textarea>` element via a save button.

Comment: @NobleMushtak — While it is possible to figure out what the problem is from the information presented, the OP should still do some basic debugging and report the results of it rather then just giving a "it doesn't work" post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `localStorage` incorrectly:

```
function doSave(){
    //Set the item in doSave()
    //localStorage.setItem("text", text.value);
}

function doLoad(){
    //Get the item in doLoad()
    //text.value = localStorage.getItem("text");
}
```

Also, read [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin)'s answer: Don't call `doSave()` and `doLoad()` when setting the `onclick` event:

```
//When the window loads...
window.onload = function(){
    saveButton = document.getElementById("save");
    saveButton.onclick = doSave;
    loadButton = document.getElementById("load");
    loadButton.onclick = doLoad;
    textarea = document.getElementById("text");
};
```

Here's the "fiddle": http://jsfiddle.net/NobleMushtak/JNKaU/

Comment: thanks al give it go , just new to html5 and javascript

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign functions to `onclick` properties. You are calling `doSave` and `doLoad` and assigning their return values. Since those functions do not have `return` statements, they return `undefined`.

Remove the `()`. Don't call them immediately.

Comment: Also, You can't access your textarea's content using `text.value` but `textarea.value`

Comment: @JbDrucker — You probably can through the horrible "DOM elements with an id get a global variable" issue that started in IE 4 and spread throughout the rest of the browser ecosystem.

Comment: @JbDrucker: ID'd elements are reliable globals now, so that will work just fine.

Comment: oryt , ok just new to this but i will try and fix it